# Prevent insertion of duplicates

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table with columns CompanyID, EmployeeCode. EmployeeCode is unique and CompanyID can be repeated. So we can keep a list of employees in Google, Apple etc.

I want a way to ensure that the same employee cannot be added if he/she is already in the database. What would be a good way to do this ? I'd prefer not to create additional columns or tables for this.

Comment: Before `insert`  get the count using `select` query with where condition depending on result you can allow to insert.

Comment: The better way to insert using `STOREPROCEDURE`

Comment: On top of @Praveen's suggestion - you can add an unique index on the values that makes the entity unique and then the database will complain if you really try to enter the same values once more.

Comment: @AllanS.Hansen - Please explain what you mean.

Comment: @PraveenS - I'd prefer that the database do this checking instead of the person inserting the row. any suggestions on how I could make such a SP ?

Comment: @Trojan If you add a unique index on the relevant fields, the database engine will not allow you to insert duplicate records.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Create a UNIQUE constraint on the column where you want to prevent duplicates:

```
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX [IX_YourTableName_EmployeeCode] ON [YourTableName] (EmployeeCode)
```

Comment: Will this work in this case - If I want the combination of two columns to be considered unique ? Ex. Number, Name. We have rows (1, Jon), (2, David), (3, Penny). Its okay if we insert (1, smith) or (7, Jon), but NOT (1,Jon)

Comment: @Trojan.ZBOT Yes, you can enforce the constraint across multiple columns.  This is called a "composite" index.  Just include the list of column names separated by commas.  Example: `CREATE UNIQUE INDEX ... (column1, column2, column3)`

Answer (score 0):

Try this..

```
Create table UniqueTable
(
CompanyID int, 
EmployeeCode int 
)

--Insert dummy data
INSERT INTO UniqueTable(EmployeeCode ,CompanyID ) Values(1,200)

--When are Going to insert duplicate Ecmployeecode '1' then it will not insert data into table
INSERT INTO UniqueTable(EmployeeCode ,CompanyID ) 
Select 1,200 From  UniqueTable t1
Left join UniqueTable t2 on 1=t2.EmployeeCode
WHERE t2.EmployeeCode  IS NULL


--We are Going to insert different Ecmployeecode '2' it will insert into table
INSERT INTO UniqueTable(EmployeeCode ,CompanyID ) 
Select 2,300 From  UniqueTable t1
Left join UniqueTable t2 on 2=t2.EmployeeCode
WHERE t2.EmployeeCode  IS NULL
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
    Create PROCEDURE [dbo].[sp_Emp_Insert]
    @EmployeeCode nvarchar(50)
    As
  Begin
  if Not Exists (select EmployeeCode from YOUR_TABlE where EmployeeCode =@EmployeeCode )
  Begin
      Insert QUERY
   End 
  else
  Return 0  
 End  

    End
```